# Tkinter window changes dimensions or resolution when I use pyplot

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, plot, tkinter, plt

First time posting, but have found these forums incredibly helpful with my python learning!

I have a problem when I call plt.plot as it's resizing my tkinter window. I've tried this in python 2.7 and 3.5 both seem to have the issue.

Below is just some sample code to re-create the problem. You don't even need to show the graph for this problem to be re-created as soon as you plot the data it resizes.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
master = Tk() 
def plotting():
    plt.plot(x)
    #plt.show()



master.minsize(width=450, height=600)
master.wm_title("Tester")

#
y = Button(master, text='START', command=plotting )
y.place(x=230, y=180)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you try using `master.resizable(width=False, height=False)` ?

Comment: The size of the Tkinter window doesn't seem to change for me. It remains the same even without setting `resizable` to `False`

Comment: @R.p.T I just tried master.resizable(width=False, height=False), but still no luck.

Comment: I'm using windows 10 and my laptop resolution is  1920*1080 if those details help anyone solve this

Comment: That's weird. Try disabling the grid_propagate and see if it works. Do, `master.grid_propagate(0)`

Comment: Ok what I noticed in the images you provided was the `before` image had the Tkinter title `Tester` and the `after` image does not have the title. Are you sure you are using the same code you have provided here?

Comment: @R.p.T Just tried master.grid_propagate(0) but still the same.
Yes I noticed that too, so I ran the code again and if you wait a few seconds the title comes back correctly after a short delay. When I took the screen shot I must have been too quick.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think there is anything wrong with this code you have provided here. It works perfectly fine like it should.

Comment: Granted I'm no expert, but I think I read somewhere that pyplot is also using tkinter. I know from some other programs I've written that pyplot uses some default DPI's. I'm wondering now if it's changing the DPI and thus the resolution of my 'tester' window.

Comment: Is there a way I can take a look at your actual code to see where the error might be? I'm guessing the code you provided here is only an example code that focuses on the problem you are facing(?). Because I cannot think of any reason why it would resize your window

Comment: @R.p.T I think I found the problem. I was going to ask you to try re-creating my display settings then I noticed I had the following set:

Comment: "Change the size of text, apps and other items: 150% (Recommended)"
When I changed that to 100% the tkinter window didn't resize on me anymore

Comment: Ok that was not a problem with the code, but you might want to post the answer anyway just in case someone else ends up with the same *problem in the future.

Comment: Is there any solution for it with using %150 scaling. It may be bug for tkinter or matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under windows customize display there's a scrollbar for:
"Change the size of text, apps and other items: 150% (Recommended)"

When I changed that to 100% the tkinter window no longer resizes.

Thank you @R.p.T for trying to assist me!

Answer (score 0):

In stead of using `plt.plot(x)`, you might want to use `plt.Figure()` first. To be more specific, `plotting()` function can be constructed as follows.

```
def plotting():
    fig = plt.Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    ax.plot(x)
```

Then, you can work on `fig` to realize the functions.